# Python scraping with Mechanize, cookies (login) and proxies

Tags: python, cookies, proxy, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I scraping a bad designed and managed government agricultural website for application data that requires me to login and kicks me out and temporarily blocks my ip (se asia, don't ask!)... So I am trying to use python and mechanize along with a proxy list ( http://proxy-hunter.blogspot.sg/2013/01/01-01-13-l1l2l3-http-proxies-1502.html ) to do the work of scraping all the permits. However, I can get my script to login but it doesnot seem to use the proxies in my set_proxies list... can anyone say as to why and suggest what I can do to fix it? I almost found an answer on StackOverflow but the answer was something like "Don't use mechanize"... well, as I already got a working script minus the proxy aspect, that isn't much of a helpful answer.

Current code (reading from an ip site to test whether the ip changes or uses the proxies - it doesn't it just prints my real ip):

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
import urllib2

# mechanize browser/cookie stuff

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)


br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

# Proxies to use

br.set_proxies({"84.2.35.44:80": "http", "1.62.68.201:6675": "http", "119.254.90.18:8080": "http"})

# Testing whether the proxy works by checking ip

page = br.open('http://whatismyipaddress.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
ip = soup.findAll('div', {'style':'text-align:center;padding-top:4px;'})
print ip
```

So that works in the terminal but comes back with my real ip, rather than any of the three proxies that were set.

Finally, please consider in your answer that I will also logging into the website in the actual code, using sth like:

```
br.open('http://www.terriblegovernmentsite.hk/login.php')
br.select_form(nr=3)
br.form[login'user'] = 'researcher01'
br.form[login'pass'] = 'mypassword'
br.submit()
```

However, this is also a bit irrelevant since I can't even get proxy to work with simple reading of a static webpage, never the mind whilst handling cookies.

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated.